# How to set php version for each site on IIS server. i tried but not run showing error

Tags: php, iis, windows-services, web-config

i tried to run Laravel 9 project on server.updating version for particular site.but showing error.any one can suggest.

web config auto change and not run project on live server.

Comment: People do need more information to understand what you meant. Please add screen shots if difficult to describe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [php manager](https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2018/05/php-manager-150-for-iis-10), it can help you manage different versions of php and it is simpler to add new php than configure fastcgi manually.

[image]

Comment: The "1.5" version of PHP Manager you pointed to is known to have bugs such as installing failures.